# $scope.$on fires twice if I go to a different page

Tags: angularjs

I've got $scope.$on('keypress' on two pages of my angular app... And it works perfectly when I reload, but if I go to the other page, it'll start firing twice. No console errors. What's happening?

```
.directive('keypressEvents', ['$document', '$rootScope', function ($document, $rootScope) {
    function link($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        //console.log($document, $element, $scope, $attrs);
        $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
            //console.log(e.key);
            var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            if (key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3 || key == 4 || key == 5 || key == 6) {
                //alert(key);
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
}]);
```

I'm thinking it might be because of $document.bind?

Comment: make sure you register the directive only once. And on destroy of the directive you should remove the event listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are registering your event with global scope i.e $rootScope

```
   "$rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);"
```

So when you move to other page your $rootScope remain same and registers a another listener.Therefore, both are working at same time try with this

```
$scope.$broadcast
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you bind the 'keypress' event on $document. The observed behavior seems normal if you call the directive twice, you will get 2 calls per keypress action.

Instead of using it as a directive, you could bind the event in your main controller using only :

```
$document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        //console.log(e.key);
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3 || key == 4 || key == 5 || key == 6) {
            //alert(key);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
        }
    });
```

Then, don't forget to unbind the document if you leave the main controller (which should happend when you're leaving the app) :

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        $document.unbind('keypress');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! The first part works great but I think $destroy isn't working. Now the keypress won't fire if I load a new page.